# How to filter array of nested objects with unknown depth based on given search term

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion

There are similar answers here but all of the ones I've seen and tested don't go pass two levels deep, so I don't think this is a duplicate problem...I am trying to filter an array of objects. Each of its objects can have other nested objects of unknown depth. For my data, **treeView** is a collection of **treeData**, and treeNode(children) will have the same interface.

```
export interface TreeView = TreeData[]

export interface TreeData {
    label: string;
    children?: TreeData[]
}
```

```
const treeData = 
[
  {label: 'obj-1', children: [ {label: 'bananas'},{label: 'apples', children: [
       {label: 'bananas',},{label: 'apples'}, {label: 'coconut',  children: [
           {label: 'bananas'},{label: 'oranges',  },
]},
]}]},
  
{label: 'obj-2', children: [ {label: 'apples'},{label: 'apples', children: [
       {label: 'oranges',},{label: 'apples'}, {label: 'coconut',  children: [
           {label: 'bananas'},{label: 'oranges', children: [
             {label: 'bananas'},{label: 'oranges',  },
] },
]},
]}]},

  {label: 'obj-3', children: [ {label: 'apples'},{label: 'mango'},{label: 'apples', children: [
       {label: 'oranges',},{label: 'apples'}, {label: 'coconut',  children: [
           {label: 'bananas'},{label: 'oranges', children: [
             {label: 'bananas'},{label: 'mango',  },
] },
]},
]}]},
]
```

Objects with a label that don't match the searchTerm should be removed, and if an object has a children property, repeat the process. I've been trying to solve this with recursion. Here's my code...

```
const recurse = (array, searchTerm) => {
  return array.map((element) => {
  return {...element, subElements: element.subElements.filter((subElement) => subElement.label === searchTerm)}
})
}

const filterArray = (myArray,value) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < myArray.length;i++){
    if(myArray.children){
      if(myArray[i].children){
          filterArray(myArray[i].children,value) 
        }
    }
    } 
     recurse(myArray,value)
  }


console.log(filterArray(treeData,'bananas'))
```

In the example above, searching 'bananas' would filter the entire array as many level deep as necessary, removing any objects whose label prop does not equal bananas; if an object does not have children, is its **label prop** equal to the search term, if not remove it from its parent array. Thanks so much in advance!

I want to return the filtered version of the original array.Only objects with 'bananas' as their label should show here[image: Only objects with bananas in the entire array should show here]

Comment: What if an object with label != bananas has a child with label == bananas.

Comment: @James if an object has children, I want to search its children. So that object should no be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want something like this:

```js
const filterByLabel = (array, searchTerm) => {
    return array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        const children = curr.children ? filterByLabel(curr.children, searchTerm) : undefined;
        
        return curr.label === searchTerm || children?.length > 0 ? [...prev, { ...curr, children }] : prev;
    }, []);
}

filterByLabel(treeData, 'bananas');
```

Comment: Gracias! after two days of wrestling with this you've made simple and effective. Thanks again